# How to extrude curves without changing thickness?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edit-mode

This should be a simple question. I have always been bothered when making curves because the thickness always changes as the object curves. Here is an example of the problem:

[image: problem]

As you can see, the curve gets thinner. I know how to fix this, but it is a bad process. What would be the easiest way to make curves and edges that are always the same thickness?

Comment: Ctrl+Clicking is how i make my curves.

Comment: For precise turns the *Spin*  tool (Alt R) is often ideal. For more freehand modeling I typically just rotate as I extrude or use control click as Radish of the Opera mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Draw the desired squiggly curve, e.g. by Add | Curve | Bezier
   [image: step_1]
2. Add a flat path object of the desired width, e.g. by Add | Curve | Path
   [image: step_2]
3. Select the curve, click the object Data context, click the Bevel Object dropdown, and choose the flat path object, e.g. "NurbsPath" -- this will sweep the flat path object along the squiggly curve.
   [image: step_3]
4. If you want a mesh object instead of a curve object, use Object | Convert To (Alt-C)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a fix after a day. You could rotate  <kbd>R</kbd> the face/edges to adjust the direction before you extrude again to do the trick.